# How to add stored JS script to iframe

Tags: html, asp.net-core, iframe, xss

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that stores html and Js in the database. The application needs to render stored HTML and executes the stored JS on that HTML. Basically it should work similarly as JSFiddle.

But such thing is open to XSS attack. So to minimize the blast radius the solution I found is to use `iframe` with `sandbox` attribute. I am able to get it working.  Below is my sample main html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />        
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='myOuterDiv'></div>
        <iframe src="/home/html" sandbox="allow-scripts">
            
        </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>


    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Html()
    {
        var storedHtml = "<div id='myInnerDiv'></div>";
        var storedJsScript = "<script>$(function(){$('#myInnerDiv').html('foo bar');})</script>";
        var jq = "<script src='/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>";

        var content = jq+ storedHtml + storedJsScript;

        return Content(content, "text/html");
    }
```

**Questions**

1. The main page has a JS script that uses jQuery. So I have to include the jQuery in main page's header. The stored script also use jQuery. However since stored script executes inside the iframe it cannot use jQuery from the main page. So in Html() method I am including jQuery again with stored HTML. Any other solution here instead of download jQuery twice?
2. Can the script that runs inside iframe access other DOM elements that are outside the iframe, like `myOuterDiv` in this case? *(I don't want the stored script access other element so just confirming)*

Comment: newer .NET 6..so ASP.NET Core. (UPDATE: Removed older ASP.NET tag)

Comment: per my test, I didn't find a solution for it...